# How to create a group of testers on testflight

Tags: testflight

How do I create a group for 50 testers on testflight?
And how do I track how they us the app for a fixed duration of 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

First invite the testers to TestFlight.

You can assign the people in a TestFlight team to a distribution list.

Integrate the TestFlight SDK into your app so you can track the usage (sessions) on TestFlight.